# Applet JNI JVM crash

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface

We have an applet that call a third party DLL , in some case this DLL bugs and cause the java.exe to exit unexpectedly , who cause a great disagreement to the user who loose all the work done and need to reload the page to get the applet loaded again , so is there any way to load the applet again without the reloading the webpage , so the user still can finish his work ?